# How to get x / y coordinates of center height obtained by JS?

Tags: javascript, html, ecmascript-6

### What I want to do

[image: this]
I want to get the center of the height of a specific element `.main` and get the DOM element that is there.

---

### Current code

```
// Get the center of the height of .main
var mainH = document.getElementsByClassName("main").offsetHeight;
var mainHCenter = mainH / 2;

// Get the element at the center of the height of .main
var centerElm = document.elementFromPoint(x coord, y coord);
```

I want to use `document.elementFromPoint ()`, which can get an element in a specified location but,
Apparently, it is necessary to specify x coordinate / y coordinate, and I am having trouble getting it.

How can I get the "x / y coordinate at the center of the height of .main" in JS?

Please let me know if my code is already wrong.

Comment: Have you tried to use [`Element​.get​Bounding​Client​Rect()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getBoundingClientRect)?

Comment: but you already got it. I don't understand. Your center line is at x= 0 y=mainHCenter no?

Comment: @A1rPun I'll give it a try.

Comment: @vincent-d When I did that, I got an error "The provided double value is non-finite".

Comment: @A1rPun , vincent-d I have posted a question related to this question. If you do not mind, please look. -> [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55663541/how-to-get-dom-elements-in-a-particular-element)

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you are looking for? I think you were close, but you need both X and Y for a coordinate.

```js
const main = document.querySelector('.main');
const centerY = main.offsetHeight / 2;
const centerX = main.offsetWidth / 2;

const element = document.elementFromPoint(centerX, centerY);
element.classList.add('highlight');
```

```css
main {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.main {
  width: 80%;
  height: 90%;
  background-color: papayawhip;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
}

article {
  width: 90%;
  height: 15%;
  background-color: palevioletred;
  margin: 2% auto;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  color: papayawhip;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.highlight {
  background-color: white;
  color: black
}
```

```html
<main>
  <section class="main">
    <article>1</article>
    <article>2</article>
    <article>3</article>
    <article>4</article>
    <article>5</article>
  </section>
</main>
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I tried moving it with JSFiddle. Whichever `<article>` height is increased, the element in the middle is indeed highlighted. I thought it would work well in my environment too, but the acquired DOM element was not as expected.
Perhaps I think that the problem is that the property of `elementFromPoint()`: get DOM element based on **viewport**.
In addition, I'll post a question about this.

Comment: I posted a question about this issue. If you do not mind, please look. -> [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55663541/how-to-get-dom-elements-in-a-particular-element)