# How to get DOM elements in a particular element?

Tags: javascript, html, ecmascript-6

### What I want to do

[image: like this]

I want to get the center of the height of a specific element `.main` and get the DOM element that is there.

---

### What I tried

I thought I could get a DOM element with `elementFromPoint()`.

①

```
// Get the center of the height of .main
const rect = document.getElementsByClassName("main")[0].getBoundingClientRect();
const mainHCenter = rect.height / 2;
const mainWCenter = rect.width / 2;

// Get the element at the center of the height of .main
var centerElm = document.elementFromPoint(0, mainHCenter);
```

②

```
// Get the center of the height of .main
const main = document.querySelector(".main");
const centerY = main.offsetHeight / 2;
const centerX = main.offsetWidth / 2;

// Get the element at the center of the height of .main
const element = document.elementFromPoint(centerX, centerY);
```

But in either case, the retrieved DOM element was not as expected.
Apparently `elementFromPoint()` seems to get DOM elements based on **viewport**.

---

I wanted to use [`caretPositionFromPoint()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DocumentOrShadowRoot/caretPositionFromPoint), but with a small amount of browser support, this is not possible.

Q. Is there any better way to get DOM elements in a **particular** element?

Comment: Note that `elementFromPoint()` gets the highest z-indexed element at that point also. Elements under it will be shadowed. You could also get `main` depending on margins of children. What is your actual use case? Provide a live example with basic css

Comment: Also, `pointer-events: none` elements will not be returned, according to MDN - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DocumentOrShadowRoot/elementFromPoint

Comment: @charlietfl I reproduce the actual situation with JSFiddle. Please wait.

Comment: @PhistucK Perhaps that element doesn't use `pointer-events: none;`.. I'll make a real demo with JSFiddle. Please wait.

Comment: I did something very similar to this recently. Had to do a while loop with a small threshold to slide down elementFromPoint in pixel increments to get to a  child node due to margins of children would expose the parent in between

Comment: @charlietfl Oh, I see.. I created the actual situation [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/__R2D2/tw8ry5zn/). Please look.

Comment: @PhistucK I created the actual situation [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/__R2D2/tw8ry5zn/). Please look.

Comment: I got `p.active` by adding `rect.top` and `rect.left` to the mainW and mainH and using `mainWCenter` instead of zero https://jsfiddle.net/nau5Lp98/

Comment: @charlietfl Thank you! I made a mistake in the title of Fiddle meta, but please don't worry lol

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting height and width centers but not adding the offsets for main from left and top of the document

I found element `p.active` by adjusting your demo to:

```
const rect = document.getElementsByClassName("main")[0].getBoundingClientRect();

const mainHCenter = rect.top + (rect.height / 2);
const mainWCenter = rect.left + (rect.width / 2);
                  // ^^^^^   add left and top offsets


var centerElm = document.elementFromPoint(mainWCenter, mainHCenter);
                                        // ^^^ don't use zero

console.log(centerElm);// returned p.active
```

<kbd>**[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/nau5Lp98/)**</kbd>

Comment: Wow, it worked also well in my local environment! Thank you very much!

Comment: I'm really sorry, but I made it a bit hard to see due to my mistake, so please turn on the Nomarized-css of the demo CSS and make the title of Fiddle meta "DOM problem"? x(